# Convert int to binary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binary

I have a pandas data frame, of which the contents of the columns are integers. However, these integers were read from a .txt file and actually represent binary digits.

So for example, let's say one of the entries is

```
0011
```

Decimal = 3

In my table, the "0011" is stored as an 'int64' type. I want to convert this into the decimal of the binary that it represents, and I need to do this for all entries within certain columns, how do I go about this?

Comment: Note that by using `int64` as a column type, you're limiting yourself to values of `524287` or less.  That's because `int64` is limited to 19 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the contents of the columns are integers rather than string, the `int(i, 2)` function cannot be used directly on the integer i, or else it will throw an error.  E.g.

```
int(11, 2)
TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base
```

You have to firstly convert the columns to string and then convert string to decimal values.  For example, assuming column 'val', use the code:

```
df['val'] = df['val'].astype(str).map(lambda x: int(x, 2))
```

1. `astype(str)` convert the column type to string, then
2. use the `int()` function within `map()` to apply to each element in the column

Test codes and output:

```
data = { 'val': [11, 101, 1001, 1101]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
                
Output:  (before conversion)    

                 val
            0     11
            1    101
            2   1001
            3   1101
        
df['val'] = df['val'].astype(str).map(lambda x: int(x, 2))
print(df)
        
Output:  (after conversion)
        
            val
        0     3
        1     5
        2     9
        3    13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) with `base` set as 2.

Example:

```
>>> int('0011', 2)
3
```

```
from functools import partial

bin_to_int = partial(int, base=2)
s = pd.Series(['0011', '101', '1010'])
s.apply(bin_to_int)

0     3
1     5
2    10
dtype: int64
```